# Cant use document.getElementById() with createElement();

Tags: javascript, html

Why can't I use cant use `document.getElementById();` with `createElement();` ? I'm getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).createElement is not a function`. I got createElement from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement). FYI: I'm not using any javascript apis like jquery, and im not planning on either.

The code I have:

```js
document.getElementById('container1').createElement("input")
```

Comment: Look `createElement()` creates an element. Then you `append` the element to the `document.getElementById('container1')`

Comment: Oh. I must have mis understood that wrong from the docs

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementById` returns a `HTMLElement`, and `HTMLElement` doesn't have a `createElement` method

This may be what you're after:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('container1')
var child = document.createElement('input')
parent.appendChild(child)
```

Or

```
document.getElementById('container1').appendChild(document.createElement('input'))
```

Answer (score -1):

The Fix it Pretty simple.

```js
const element = document.createElement('input')
document.getElementById('container1').append(element)
```

The create Element returns an element. The secounds appends the newly created element to another element which is already rendered to the user

Comment: Thanks. I just misunderstood what I read from the documentation